# Use special loader using Angular 9

Tags: angular, webpack, angular9

I upgraded my project to Angular 9. I'm using SSR, after upgrading my `webpack.config.js` become `webpack.config.js.bak`. Now I'm trying to do `ng build --prod && ng run [projectName]:server:production`

Now I got this error message

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node 1:2
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:2)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured 
    to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

So I tried to implement loaders such as `node-loader` and I need to know should I update my `server.ts` because I can see `webpack.config.js` is no longer needed in my case.

**EDIT:**

I tried this in `angular.json` but still not working

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "externalDependencies": [
              "fabric"
            ],
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          },
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this exact issue. First your "externalDependencies" should be set to "canvas" in Angular.json. Then be sure you have the latest stable version of node installed. Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree, this is the solution, see below

Answer (score 3):

```
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            **"externalDependencies": [
              "canvas"
            ],**
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "vendorChunk": true
            },
            "ci": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
```